# merging 2 MySQL selects into a single query

Tags: mysql

I'm having some problems in getting the correct query for my needs

```
SELECT tbl_participants.name, 
       tbl_transactions.consumer_rfid, 
       tbl_transactions.trans_price 
FROM   tbl_participants, 
       tbl_transactions 
WHERE  tbl_participants.id = tbl_transactions.trader_id
```

What I have is 2 simple table: one stored the participants (traders/consumers) the other one the transactions (form trader to consumer). I'm trying to bring back the following information: trader's name, consumer's name and price of transaction

tbl_participants has id(unique), name (of participant)
tbl_transactions has trader_id(taken from above table), consumer rfid(taken from above table)

my query should return the trader's name (based on id), consumer's name (based on rfid) and value of transaction

Thank you

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you want here. It seems like you can just remove `consumer_rfid`. It also seems like you can try using a `UNION`.

Comment: I want it being displayed as a table where the header of the table would be name | consumer name | price. A union would put the data under the previous table and not next to it.

Comment: It seems like the second query is the same query as the first, with just fewer fields in the SELECT.  As such, your first query already contains all the data in your second, thus no need to "merge"

Comment: Please update your question and post your desired result set.

Comment: Just use whatever you consumer_name field is instead of consumer_rfid.  You have not given enough information about your table schema for us to tell you more. How you display the results on your screen is up to you.

Comment: There is no difference between the two queries except the columns are different. You are joining the two tables on the same columns, so the data will be the same.

Comment: @Adrian can you post your table structure for each table?

Comment: @Adrian use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_participants;` to create a table for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a semi-wild guess from reading the comments:

```
SELECT tbl_participants.name AS consumer,
       tbl_transactions.trans_price AS price
FROM   tbl_participants,
       tbl_transactions
WHERE  tbl_participants.id = tbl_transactions.trader_id;
```

I can't make up what you mean by `name | consumer name | price`...

**EDIT**: After some more information, this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT p1.name AS name,
       p2.name AS consumer_name,
       t.trans_price AS price
FROM   tbl_participants p1,
       tbl_participants p2,
       tbl_transactions t
WHERE  p1.id = t.trader_id
AND    p2.card_rfid = t.consumer_rfid;
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanations. The header of the table should display the trader, the consumer and the price of the transaction. The usual query brings back exactly these information however for the consumer it brings back the rfid tag as this is located within the transaction table. What I want is to replace that rfid tag with the name of the consumer, name that can be found in the participants table (both traders and consumers are located in participants table)

Comment: Whoever's downvoting this, I'm also trying to help, you know!
@Adrian for that you need the consumer id... Is it `tbl_transactions.consumer_id`?

Comment: both traders and consumer share the same tbl_participants as at any given point a trader could be a consumer and vice-versa

Comment: Sorry, what I meant whas: in what field from the `tbl_transactions` table is the id of the consumer stored? (Like the trader is stored in `tbl_transactions.trader_id`...)

Comment: in the tbl_transactions there is an id for the trader (trader_id) but no id for the consumer, only the rfid of the consumer.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the consumer's id from the rfid? (P.S. Some table structures would be very helpful!)

Comment: yes, the consumer's rfid is located in the tbl_participants.card_rfid

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you sooooo very much, been working on it for a good few hours without any luck. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   SELECT tbl_participants.name AS consumer, 
           tbl_transactions.consumer_rfid, 
           tbl_transactions.trans_price 
    FROM   tbl_participants, 
           tbl_transactions 
    WHERE  tbl_participants.id = tbl_transactions.trader_id
```

I don't understand your question you are using the same two tables. So a select can be done without any problem.

**EDIT** If you don't want the consumer_rfid just remove it.

```
    SELECT tbl_participants.name AS consumer,
    tbl_transactions.trans_price 
    FROM   tbl_participants,tbl_transactions
    WHERE  tbl_participants.id = tbl_transactions.trader_id
```

Comment: This is not helpful. I won't downvote because it's OP's fault.

Comment: @Adrian is the name of the trader stored in tbl_transaction? Or do you have a table called tbl_trader?

Comment: All you did is give an alias for `tbl_participants.name`.

Comment: @njk No sorry he ask to basically to merge two queries. B.T.W. my answer doesn't materially differ from Mart McVry so.

Comment: @Adrian does your table tbl_participants have a way to make out this is a trader or consumer? E.g. type = 1 for trader and 0 for consumer?

Comment: @njk I suggest you read the changes from start of the OP post until now. Mart McVry steals my thunder, I made the same post as he did 3 minute before. The OP only answers the questions from Mart McVry. I have tried multiple times to get more info from the OP.

Comment: @njk I had completed this post before Mart. Mart posts the exact same answer.For some strange reason you pick me out to complain.
The OP first started with the question I have two queries I like to merge. I immediately shaw that he was querying the same two tables. So, I though why not just sent him the correct SQL query.
I have tried multiple times to contact the OP, but he refuses every attempt from my side to clarify his question. I was even working on a SQL fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf28/1) to help answer this post. And then you give me a downvote. Why?